# Android TextToSpeech doesn't work

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I would like to use TTS in my application. First of all I'm trying to run some examples, but every time TTS doesn't work on my device. In example I have the code:

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.tts;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
private TextToSpeech textToSpeech;
private Button button;
private EditText inputText; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    inputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputText);
    textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            convertTextToSpeech();
        }   
    });
    convertTextToSpeech();
}


@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        int result = textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.US);
        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            Log.e("error", "This Language is not supported");
        } else {
            convertTextToSpeech();
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("error", "Initilization Failed!");
    }
}   

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    textToSpeech.shutdown();
    super.onDestroy();
}   

private void convertTextToSpeech() {
    //String text = "test";
    String text = inputText.getText().toString();
    if (null == text || "".equals(text)) {
        text = "Please give some input.";
    }
    textToSpeech.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".TextToSpeechActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/inputText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/inputText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/inputText"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="Speak" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

After typing the word and clicking button application says nothing. 
Does anyone have an idea how to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have TTS on the device?

Comment: @Breadbin I have "Google Text-to-speech". It has been downloaded automatically when i first time run one of TTS examples.

Comment: No exception thrown? No error message in the logcat?